# Error Converting Datetime to string, Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string.

Tags: php, datetime

This code errors on line 18 due to converting datetime to a string I tried it without the (string) and had the same issue although it did work on another page

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","workAcc","storm111274","work"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
echo "Tell Bertie or who ever does IT";
}
$sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM downstairs WHERE ID = ".htmlspecialchars($_GET["ID"]) .";";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlSelect);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)  > 1){
echo "error too many rows this really really shouldn't happen";
}elseif(mysqli_num_rows($result)  === 0){
 echo "No record found";  
}else{
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$sDate = date_create($row["StartTime"]);
$eDate = date_create($row["EndTime"]);
echo $row["ID"] . "_" . $row["Course"] . "_" . (string)date_format($sDate, "H:i") . "_" . (string)date_format($eDate, "H:i") . "_" . $eDate . "_" . $row["Room"] . "_" . $row["Instructor"];
}}
?>
```

Comment: What is the format of `$row["StartTime"]` and `$row["EndTime"]`

Comment: You dont need to cast to `(string)` as the result of that function is a string

Comment: What data type is StartTime and EndTime on your database?

Answer (score 0):

There is an `$eDate` in this concatenated string:

```
echo $row["ID"] . "_" . $row["Course"] . "_" . (string)date_format($sDate, "H:i") . "_" 
    . (string)date_format($eDate, "H:i") . "_" . $eDate  // <<<< Here
    . "_" . $row["Room"] . "_" . $row["Instructor"];
```

`$eDate` is a `DateTime` object. When you join it to the string with `.` PHP tries to convert it to a string, and that's when you get the error you're seeing. To fix the error, either remove the `$eDate` or convert it to a string with `date_format`.

I'm not sure how you want it to look, so I can't suggest a way to fix it, but the `(string)` casts on the other `date_format` results are not necessary.

Comment: It was originally just $eDate and that worked for one page but on this one it failed

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

date_format($sDate, "H:i")->format('H:i')

Comment: I tried that but got this error

[Thu Jul 21 08:04:33.662289 2016] [:error] [pid 14050] [client 164.39.153.200:65193] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on string in getData.php:18\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in getData.php on line 18, referer: http://xxxx.xx/work/insert.php